# WYSWYG web editor for Sharepoint

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint, content-management-system, wcm

Is there any approach to have a simple WYSWYG free web editor (preferably drag'n'drop widgets -based) embedded or integrated into Sharepoint 2010?

I am shocked because this answer seems to not exist... So far I've found...

- Plugins for integrating Sharepoint into Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress, but I want the opposite, using those interfaces to create content stored in Sharepoint, without having to export HTMLs and adapting them to SP arquitecture and metadata. If not, I cannot even find any way to export a Wordpress/Drupal site into Sharepoint.
- Web content rich editor: Am I doing something wrong is this just an html loader that does not edit a thing?
- Webparts: all seem to be costly, and I am not sure there even exists a nice one for that concrete task

Could somebody point me to the most optimal solution for non-tech users using this feature? Thank you

By the way, is there any public web part repository from microsoft. Even searching that in google does not throw any interesting info..

Answer (score 0):

Most public, open source projects for Microsoft can be found at http://www.codeplex.com/.

Regarding your requirement, if I understand correctly, you want to have a way to store content in SharePoint for display in a drupal or other CMS. The content should be in HTML format.  If I understand you correctly, the easiest way to do this is to create a basic SharePoint list, add a multiline column and set the type of text to Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks).  When you add an item to the list, the form will include a form element that has a WYSWYG editor.

I've integrated SharePoint with Linux before using Curl. It's not easy, but can be done.